# jdbc Mysql nested resultset

Tags: java, mysql, resultset

See Below. `rs.getString("tags")` is subquery with more than 1 row. I want to iterate that subquery(rs.getString("tags") ----  Like `rs.next()`.

```
while (rs.next()) {

        emailDto emaildto = new emailDto();         

        emaildto.setMid(rs.getInt("id"));
        emaildto.setSub(rs.getString("sub"));
        emaildto.setMessage(rs.getString("message"));

         while(rs.getString("tags").next()){

            arrtags[i] = rs.getString(1);
         }

        emaildto.setTags(arrtags);
```

`rs.getString("tags")` does not work  --- and contain more than 1 rows. How to extract it. Is there any technique?

Comment: Please share more code, at least the query you're using.

Comment: Hi Mick, here is my complete code. see below

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

Array tagsArray = rs.getArray("tags");
String[] tags = (String[])tagsArray.getArray();

Answer (score 0):

this is not answer. this is complete code

List emails = new ArrayList();

```
    String listQuery = "select mid, sub, message, "
    + " (select emailid from sub_ids where sub_ids.messageid= sub_mail_list.mid )  //  this query fetch more than one row.
```

as refid"
        + " from sub_mail_list";

```
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs;
    try {

        ps = DatabaseConnectionUtil.getConnection().prepareStatement(
                listQuery);



         rs = ps.executeQuery(listQuery);

        while (rs.next()) {
            emailDto emaildto = new emailDto();         

            emaildto.setMid(rs.getInt("mid"));
            emaildto.setSub(rs.getString("sub"));
            emaildto.setMessage(rs.getString("message"));

            Array tagsArray =  rs.getArray("refid");

        List<vtbDto> vtbdtosvr = new ArrayList<vtbDto>();



        int[] tags = (int[])tagsArray.getArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {


                vtbDto vtbdto = new vtbDto();



                vtbdto.setRefid(tags[i]);

                vtbdtosvr.add(vtbdto);

            }







            emaildto.setAr(tagsArray);

            emails.add(emaildto);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        DatabaseConnectionUtil.closeAll(ps);
    }

    return emails;
```

And this is code to print function

List emailDtos = emaildao.getAllemails();

```
            for (emailDto emailDto2 : emailDtos) {

                  System.out.println( emailDto2.getMid());
                  System.out.println( emailDto2.getSub());
                  System.out.println( emailDto2.getMessage());



                  List<vtbDto> vtbdtos= emailDto2.getVtbdtolst();


                  for (vtbDto vtbdto2 : vtbdtos) {
                      System.out.print(vtbdto2.getRefid() + ", ");
                  }


               }
```

and the console print "Subquery returns more than 1 row";